# Sub String using FixedLengthRecord of Apache Bindy

Tags: apache, apache-camel, bindy

I am using apache bindy and have used **@FixedLengthRecord**

```
@DateField(columnName="Name", pos=1, length=10)
private String name;
```

Now is there any functionality that when the name field is more than 10 characters then we can substring only 10 characters of it?

I belive trim is only for trimming blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got the solution. 
Using clip=true does the work

```
@DateField(columnName="Name", pos=1, length=10, clip=true)
```